# Convert datetime formate dd/mm/yyyy 12:14 to dd/july/yyyy using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert my date time to the `dd/july/yyyy` using javascript. 
I have variable

```
var v = 29/09/2015 12:00
```

and  want to convert it into `29-july-2015`.

Comment: You have `var v = 29/09/2015 12:00`  or `var v = "29/09/2015 12:00"` - Please edit your question telling use the exact variable containing the exact data since now you have September and July

Comment: @ mplungjanvar no not in this formate v = "29/09/2015 12:00"

Comment: In what format exactly then. I do not want to know in what format you do NOT have it

Comment: Also in your title you say dd/july/yyyy but in the text you say 29-july-2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your var is in quotes.

```js
// note JS months are 0 based

var month = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

function conv(str) {
  var dateParts = str.split(" ")[0].split("/");
  return dateParts[0]+"-"+month[dateParts[1]-1]+"-"+dateParts[2];
}
  
alert(conv("29/09/2015 12:00"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using moment.js

http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Please wait until you can comment to comment. This is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Using momentjs.js, you can achieve this by below code

```
var newDate = moment("29/01/2015 12:00" ,"DD-MM-YYYY").format('DD-MMM-YY');;

console.log(newDate);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function displayDate(){
var now = new Date();
var today=now.getDate();
var month=now.getMonth();
var monthName=new Array(12)
 monthName[0]="January";
 monthName[1]="February";
 monthName[2]="March";
 monthName[3]="April";
 monthName[4]="May";
 monthName[5]="June";
 monthName[6]="July";
 monthName[7]="August";
 monthName[8]="September";
 monthName[9]="October";
 monthName[10]="November";
 monthName[11]="December";
var year=now.getFullYear();
var day=now.getDay();

console.log(today+"-"+monthName[month]+ "-"+year);
}
displayDate();
```

Comment: i got your answer but var date=29/09/2015 12:00 is as a input to my function and want output as 29-july-2015.